# Why can not load so in Cocos2d-x in Android4.1,4.2?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-3.0

**Background**

It can not load the third *.so files on Cocos2d-x in  Android4.1,4.2.

While at other newer android system, such as, android 4.3  etc, my project can load the *.so files correctly.

**Error Log**

```
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:148) at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 02-03 12:52:37.521 24884-24884/? E/linker: load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" not found

02-03 12:52:37.521 24884-24884/? E/linker: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1652): could not load library > "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" needed by "libwlgame.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:759): library > "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" not found

02-03 12:52:37.521 24884-24884/? E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.tencent.tmgp.weile.jiaxiangmj-1/> libwlgame.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1652): could not load library > "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" needed by "libwlgame.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:759): library > "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" not found

02-03 12:52:37.527 24884-24884/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1652): could not load library > "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" needed by "libwlgame.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:759): library > "libhuanyu-sdk-jni.so" not found at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372) at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514) at weile.games.AppActivity.<clinit>(AppActivity.java:15) at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1125) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-03 12:52:37.539 587-608/? E/AppErrorDialog: Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance

02-03 12:52:37.569 587-24907/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for > com.bbk.launcher2.timeline.provider 02-03 12:52:38.129 587-605/? E/AudioService: handleConfigurationChanged() createInstance IAudioServiceExt fail
```

Answer (score 0):

**How the Cocos2d load *so file ？**

1. Load *so file by the name provided by AndroidManifest.xml.

   ```
   <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.app.lib_name"
       android:value="MyGame" />
   ```
2. The loading way, only load one so file, in cocos2d-x open source code :

   protected void onLoadNativeLibraries() {

   ```
       try {

           ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

           Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
           String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");
           System.loadLibrary(libName);
       } 
   catch (Exception e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   @Override

   protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       this.hideVirtualButton();

       onLoadNativeLibraries();

       sContext = this;
       this.mHandler = new Cocos2dxHandler(this);

       Cocos2dxHelper.init(this);

       this.mGLContextAttrs = getGLContextAttrs();
       this.init();

       if (mVideoHelper == null) {
           mVideoHelper = new Cocos2dxVideoHelper(this, mFrameLayout);
       }

       if(mWebViewHelper == null){
           mWebViewHelper = new Cocos2dxWebViewHelper(mFrameLayout);
       }

       if(mEditBoxHelper == null){
           mEditBoxHelper = new Cocos2dxEditBoxHelper(mFrameLayout);
       }

       Window window = this.getWindow();
       window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

       this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   }
   ```
3. Dynamic files dependency and load mechanism in different  Android system ?

   Yes. Newer systems than Android4.1,4.2 has better flexibility.
4. How to fix it on Android4.1,4.2 ?

   *Adhere to ：*

   a. Do not add indirect library to generate  LOCAL_MODULE.

   b. Load the libraries depended firstly，before depending module. Such as,

   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       myProCoco2dx rtcEngine = myProCoco2dx.getInstance();
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       rtcEngine.init(getApplicationContext(), appId);

   }

   The myProCoco2dx.getInstance(); make sure the  myProCoco2dx is loaded firstly.